# Draft.js - How to make smooth real-time editor with grammar checking functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, web-worker, draftjs

I tried to make a rich text editor with real-time grammar checking functionality.
I have my own dictionary and checking engine.

The problem here is the editor is not smooth as checking engine is run each time I make changes to draft.js editor even if I just move the cursor position.

Here is my RichTextEditor component.

```
import {updateEditorState, checkEditorState} from './logic/actions';
...
class RichTextEditor extends React.Component {

    ...
    onChange = (editorState) => {
        this.props.updateEditorState(editorState);
        this.props.checkEditorState(editorState);
    }
    ...
    render() {
        return (<Editor
                        editorState={this.props.editorState}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    updateEditorState: bindActionCreators(updateEditorState, dispatch),
    checkEditorState: bindActionCreators(checkEditorState, dispatch)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RichTextEditor);
```

*logic/actions.js*

```
import * as actionTypes from './rteActionTypes'
...
export const updateEditorState = (data) => {
    return ({
        type: actionTypes.UPDATE_EDITOR_STATE,
        data: data
    });
}

export const checkEditorState = (data) => {
    return ({
        type: actionTypes.CHECK_EDITOR_STATE,
        data: data
    });
}
...
```

*logic/saga.js*

```
import { takeLatest, all, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as actionTypes from './rteActionTypes';

import { checkEditorState } from './CheckEngine';

function* checkEditor(action) {
    const {updated, editorState} = yield call(checkEditorState, action.data)
    if (updated) {
        yield put({ type: actionTypes.UPDATE_EDITOR_STATE, data: editorState })
    }
}

export default function* saga() {
    yield all([
        takeLatest(actionTypes.CHECK_EDITOR_STATE, checkEditor)
    ]);
}
```

*logic/reducer.js*

```
import * as actionTypes from './rteActionTypes';
import {
    EditorState,
    CompositeDecorator,
    convertFromRaw
} from 'draft-js';
const initialState = {
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(decorator),
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.UPDATE_EDITOR_STATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                editorState: action.data
            };
    ...
    }
}
```

I know this implementation is not a good practise because the UI will be blocked until the redux action is dispatched successfully and that's the main reason for non-smooth editing.
I want to make a background thread which detects the changes of store variable 'editorState'.
Once the change is detected, it runs checkEngine and then dispatches a new redux action to update the editorState with grammar checked editorState.

> But I don't know how to create a background thread or a worker for redux store in React.js
>   Can you help me with this problem?
>   Thanks.